# Warning: pg_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\grafig\read.php on line 6

Tags: php, postgresql

What's wrong in the code??

```
<?php
$host       =  "localhost";
$dbuser     =  "tesdb";
$dbpass     =  "123456";
$dbname    =  "tesdb";

// script koneksi php postgree
$dbcon = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host", $dbuser, $dbpass); 

//$query ="SELECT * FROM air_tanah.pembayaran";
$query ="select * from air_tanah.pembayaran";
$result = pg_query($dbcon, $query) or die('Query failed');

  // output result
  while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo "    Denda: " . $line['denda'] ."    Penyimpan: " . $line['Penyimpan'] .  "<br/>";
  }

  // free result
  pg_free_result($result);

  // close connection
  pg_close($dbcon);
?>
```

and error like this

Warning: pg_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\grafig\read.php on line 12
Query failed

Comment: It seems that `$dbcon` is an instance and not a database resource to identify the connection. Please edit your question and add the code where you assign the value for this variable.

Answer (score 1):

The code which you have entered does not allow us to really answer to your problem, we would need to know what is assigned to `$dbcon` variable.

`pg_query` expects there to be an instance of a Resource which holds the connection. Such resource is created using `pg_connect` or `pg_pconnect` method so we would need to see the contents of your `db_con.php` file: be sure to remove any credentials (hide them with * symbols for example).

It seems that something else actively sets the variable: are you sure that you have created a connection using `pg_connect` and not PDO for example (which would answer why you have there an object and not resource).